# Updating JSON in XQuery and Marklogic 8

Tags: json, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

I've got a simple enough JSON document stored in Marklogic:

```
{ "title": "mytitle", "edition": "1" }
```

Is there a way I can add a new field using Xquery functions so my document and object end up looking is this?

```
{ "title": "mytitle", "edition": "1", "date": "2016-01-01" }
```

There apparently is support for JSON manipulation via xdmp:node-replace, xdmp:insert-child-after, etc found in the documentation here: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/json#id_60123

I have had 0 luck with the above. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you only need to insert a property, you first have to wrap the property/value in an `object-node`, then select the property child:

```
xdmp:node-insert-child(
  doc('/mydoc.json')/node(),
  object-node { "date": "2016-01-01" }/date)
```